# Is starting a sentence with "or" acceptable?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis

The sentence(s) I want to use is

> Even if the claims above were true, this sort of logic is consequentialist in nature. Or, more accurately, specifically consequentialist since it is concerned not with humanity as a whole but instead with a subsection of humanity, namely the inhabitants of a particular territory.

I also fear that it's a bit too wordy, does it strike you that way?

Comment: This reads like specialist language from some academic discipline with which I am not familiar, so, for non-specialist readers wordiness is the least of the problems with the text. So, too, is starting a sentence with 'Or..'. There is no rule that forbids starting sentences with 'Or'. If you wish to communicate with readers you do need to be sure that they are on the same wavelength as you, but if they are, by all means start your sentences with Or, But And and so forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second sentence is not a complete sentence.  Or, in other words,  I say that starting a sentence with "or" is not a problem but your sentence is suffering in other ways.